# Laravel @include and @yield blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm currently using the Laravel Blade template engine to generate pages. I'm using a default page to render everything. The problem is that I can't seem to get every css in the head part. The menu has a custom css that I eventually want to include into the head. This way I can use every part individually. How come the css doesn't get included into the head.blade.php part?

**Default.blade.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        @include('includes.head')
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">

                <header class="row">
                    @include('includes.menu')
                </header>

                <div id="main" class="row">
                    @yield('content')
                </div>

            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**head.blade.php**

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
@yield('styles')
```

**menu.blade.php**

```
@section('styles')
    <link href="{{ asset('/css/menu.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
@endsection
```

**login.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('styles')
    @parent
    <link href="{{ asset('/css/login.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
@endsection

@section('content')
--content here--
@stop
```

What I eventually want is that every individual css gets loaded into the head file based on the included views.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my grain of sand. You can organize them this way to have blade recognize sections defined in the master template (default.blade.php in your case)

**default.blade.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    @yield('head')
    @yield('styles')
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">

      <header class="row">
        @yield('primarymenu')
      </header>

      <div id="main" class="row">
        @yield('content')
      </div>

    </div>
    @yield('scripts')
  </body>
</html>
```

Notice I added scripts section ^^^, which later will also be populated within each component (menu, login)

**includes/head.blade.php**

```
@section('head')
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
@endsection
```

**includes/menu.blade.php**

```
@section('primarymenu')
  <!-- here goes your navitation links -->
@endsection

@section('styles')
  @parent
  <link href="{{ asset('/css/menu.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
@endsection

@section('scripts')
  @parent
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset ('js/menu.js') }}"></script>
@endsection
```

**login.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')
  @include('includes.head')
  @include('includes.menu')
  <!-- here goes your login contents -->
@endsection

@section('styles')
  @parent
  <link href="{{ asset('css/login.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
@endsection

@section('scripts')
  @parent
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset ('js/login.js') }}"></script>
@endsection
```

Also notice the use of [@parent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#extending-a-layout) which also helps when you want to append more content in a section where other components might have already filled with content.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Default.blade.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        @section('head')
            @include('includes.head')
        @show
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">

            <header class="row">
                @include('includes.menu')
            </header>

            <div id="main" class="row">
                @yield('content')
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

`@section ... @show` is same as `@yield` but showing immidiately

**head.blade.php**

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

then if you want to add more styles to head do like this in **menu.blade.php**

```
@section('head')
@parent
    <link href="{{ asset('/css/menu.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
@endsection
```

or if you want to replace all styles do this without `@parent`

Comment: While this does load the css for the login.blade.php, the css for the menu still doesn't show up.

Comment: place your `@yield('styles')` in **Default.blade.php** after `@include` and it will work

Comment: That returns inline css. I prefer to have all my css in the head. Guess it's not possible using the blade engine.